# Cf push fail to deploy Spring boot application in clod foundary

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am developing spring boot application and while deploying through cf push< application>,I am getting error 
Creating route demo.cfapps.io failed

My application name is demo and 
Cloud env is cloud foundary

I  tried deploying through STS as well as cf,but both the way I didn't succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cf push APP-NAME creates a URL route to your application in the form HOST.DOMAIN, where HOST is your APP-NAME and DOMAIN is specified by your administrator. Your DOMAIN isshared-domain.com. For example: cf push my-app creates the URL my-app.shared-domain.com 
It seems demo hostname is already there in cloud foundary.So you need to change host name through below command.in your case just

```
cf push demo -n demo001
```

Same way you need to change appname in sts while deployment process wizard asks.